# Styling the android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar with AppCompat from styles.xml

Tags: android, material-design, android-support-library, android-appcompat

I've got a problem with styling a Toolbar inside a CoordinatorLayout / AppBarLayout from my `styles.xml` file in combination with using AppCompat from the 23.1.1 support libraries.

**The problem I want to solve:** My activity is used from different app projects, all of which use `Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar`. Some apps have light primary colors where everything is fine. Some, however, have dark primary colors that would require setting `android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"` on the Toolbar in the activity's layout file - which I cannot do as the same code and resource files are used by the other apps as well.

**EDIT: I think I got this solved now. Keeping the `styles.xml` as it was, in the Activity I now inherit the actionBarTheme as follows (got the idea from reading http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.styleable.html#Theme_toolbarStyle):**

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/webview_toolbar"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="?attr/actionBarTheme"/>
```

See the following related questions and blog posts:

- [How do I style appcompat-v7 Toolbar like Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26503149/how-do-i-style-appcompat-v7-toolbar-like-theme-appcompat-light-darkactionbar)
- https://chris.banes.me/2014/11/12/theme-vs-style/
- [How do I style appcompat-v7 Toolbar like Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26503149/how-do-i-style-appcompat-v7-toolbar-like-theme-appcompat-light-darkactionbar)
- [When should one use Theme.AppCompat vs ThemeOverlay.AppCompat?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27238433/when-should-one-use-theme-appcompat-vs-themeoverlay-appcompat)

After reading all of the above, I tried to solve my problem by deriving an app theme from `Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar` (instead of *.NoActionBar) in those apps that have dark primary colors and applying all styles that let the action bar go away. Out of despair, I have even tried to set actionBarTheme and actionBarStyle.

My app has a `styles.xml` file that looks like this:

```
<style name="MyTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/myDarkRed</item>
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/myRed</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/myOrange</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="actionBarTheme">@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar</item>
    <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar</item>
</style>
```

My activity (derived from `AppCompatActivity`) has a `layout.xml` that looks like this:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/webview_toolbar"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

Unfortunately, my Activity still has dark text color on the toolbar. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You can add titleTextStyle and achieve that.

Comment: Now, after being desperate enough to ask for help, I finally found something that might be what I need: use "?attr" to inherit the theme from the app does work. Will edit my post.

Answer (score 0):

this one work for me

```
<style name="MyToolbarTheme">
        <!-- Used to tint the back arrow, menu and spinner arrow -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">#ffffff</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">#ffffff</item>
        <item name="drawerArrowStyle">@style/DrawerArrowStyle</item>
        <item name="colorControlNormal">#ff0000</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">#ffffff</item>
        <item name="android:textColorHighlight">#ffffff</item>
        <item name="actionOverflowMenuStyle">@style/CMOptionsMenu</item>
        <item name="searchViewStyle">@style/MySearchViewStyle</item>

    </style>

    <style name="CMOptionsMenu" parent="Widget.AppCompat.PopupMenu.Overflow">
        <item name="android:popupBackground">#ffffff</item>
    </style>

    <style name="MySearchViewStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.SearchView">
        <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/black</item>
    </style>
```

Comment: This one seems to work - however, it does define everything by itself rather than deriving it from the ThemeOverlay, which might cause side-effects with other widgets (although I didn't notice any).

Comment: you want complete style.xml??

Answer (score 0):

You can set on Toolbar your own generic style

`android:theme="@style/myToolBarLightOrDark"`

then in styles.xml set inheriting it from Light or Dark ThemeOverlay ActionBar.

Comment: `<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            android:theme="@style/MainActionBar"/>`

android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #13: Binary XML file line #13: Error inflating class android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar

if I change to app:theme="@style/MainActionBar"   it works fine but deprecated warning