# Android themes and styles: how can I find my way in this jungle?

Tags: android, android-theme, android-styles

I have been wrestling for at least one year with trying to understand how to master/get insight into Themes and Styles, but haven't come further than grasping parent relationships (and I think I read somewhere that such relations behave more like macro's rather than like true inheritance.)

To give a simple example: [this nice looking SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26504082/605463) frustrates me: what is the relationship between themes, styles, platforms, support library, API levels, etc... (and not speaking of the fact that custom styles don't need to use "parent", a dot notation suffices - why is this so different?)

The link talks about beasts such as ThemeOverlay, "?attr/colorPrimary", "app:popupTheme", device themes, native themes; where are all those beasts? How can I use them? What do they mean?

Android dev doc [admits](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html#PlatformStyles) that this is all poorly documented, and suggest to dive into the source code. but I don't feel much to explore the link they give. I mean - I'm sure I will find out if I dive into the source code, but I have better things to do than debug AOSP... And if I look at eg [this](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.style.html#Widget_Toolbar), all I get is a *totally* useless literal.

I'm aware this sounds daunting, but I can't get to reach my arms around this "big mama"... It feels like if one was not part of the AOSP movement from the beginning, it's very difficult to catch up.

Comment: Dan Lew's articles (and talk) are a good starting point: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Jr8hJdVGHAk -  http://blog.danlew.net/2014/11/19/styles-on-android/

Comment: thanks  - the succulent part starts [here](https://youtu.be/Jr8hJdVGHAk?t=22m14s), but is only a small pain relief :-) (and obviously not only in my mind...)